# Python variable with multilines

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm trying to do the following thing:
I made this code, which works fine:

```
import csv
import os

#Création fichiers BD
with open('data.csv') as datas:
    reader = csv.reader(datas, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        vlanid = row[0]
        vlanname = row[1]

        config = '''\
        resource "aci_bridge_domain" "vlan_%s_bd" {
          name               = "VLAN-%s-BD"
          tenant_dn          = aci_tenant.l2transit.id
          name_alias         = "%s"
          arp_flood          = "yes"
          relation_fv_rs_ctx = aci_vrf.l2transit.id
        }

        ''' % (vlanid, vlanid, vlanname)


        file_name = 'vlan-%s-bd.tf'% (vlanid)
        file_path = 'C:\iac\script_aci\\bd'
        file_complete = os.path.join(file_path, file_name)

        with open(file_complete, 'w') as f:
           f.writelines(config)
```

Only thing that bother me is how variable shown in the "config" block.
Using the %s method works fine, but lets say that this block had like 100 variables in it, it would be a nightmare to understand which variable is what.

My goal here is to have the variables names in the block directly instead of the "%s"

Could you guys help a newbie in the need?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#f-strings-support-for-self-documenting-expressions-and-debugging) would be an improvement.

You can use multi-line f-strings.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I've been doing some research and test about f-strings and was having some issues. Untill I understand how to escape a single curly brace.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the reply. I've been doing some research and test about f-strings and was having some issues. Until I understand how to escape a single curly brace.

Here is the modifications that now works.
Thanks a lot for the reply !

```
import csv
import os

#Création fichiers BD
with open('data.csv') as datas:
    reader = csv.reader(datas, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        vlan_id = row[0]
        vlan_name = row[1]

        config = \
        f'''resource "aci_bridge_domain" "vlan_{vlan_id}_bd" {{
          name               = "VLAN-{vlan_id}-BD"
          tenant_dn          = aci_tenant.l2transit.id
          name_alias         = "{vlan_name}"
          arp_flood          = "yes"
          relation_fv_rs_ctx = aci_vrf.l2transit.id
        }}
        '''
        
        file_name = f'vlan-{vlan_id}-bd.tf'
        file_path = 'C:\iac\script_aci\\bd'
        file_complete = os.path.join(file_path, file_name)

        with open(file_complete, 'w') as f:
           f.writelines(config)
```